# How do i easily convert a JSON-Schema into a VSCode Extension?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I wanted to use a couple of Schemas as VSCode Extension, but how do I do it?

I tried to include them in my Settings, but it would be easier for my friends that are new to programming if they could just use the Extension.